# Getting 404 error in MVC 4 deployed project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, window.location

The page is sending a request with the filter values via JavaScript to a controller action:

```
 function ItemListModel(row) {
    var self = this;
    self.Date = row[0];
    self.Rank = row[1];
    self.UserID = row[2];
    self.Last = row[3];
    self.First = row[4];
    self.Middle = row[5];
    self.Serial = row[6];
    self.ECN = row[7];
    self.MAC = row[8];
    self.Clinical = row[9];
    self.Make = row[10];
    self.Model = row[11];
    self.Dept = row[12];
}

function Export() {
    var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
    var arr = new Array();
    $("tfoot input").each(function (i) {
        var test = $(this).val();
        arr.push(test);
    });
    var model = [];
    model = new ItemListModel(arr);
    window.location.href = "/Inventory/ExportSheet?model=" + JSON.stringify(model);
}
```

And the action is:

```
 public void ExportSheet(string model)
    {
        ItemsListModel reportmodel = new ItemsListModel();
        if (model != null)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serl = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            reportmodel = (ItemsListModel)serl.Deserialize(model, typeof(ItemsListModel));
        }
        DataTable dt = ReportsRepository.GetItemsListParms(CleanReportParms(reportmodel));
        dt.Columns.Add("DateIssued");
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            DateTime date = row.Field<DateTime>("Date Issued");
            string newdate = date.ToShortDateString();
            row.SetField("DateIssued", newdate);
        }
        dt.Columns.Remove("Date Issued");
        DumpExcel(dt, "itemlist");
    }
```

I am using EPPlus to create a spreadsheet for downloading to the browser.  This works perfectly well on my development box but once it is deployed I am getting this error:

```
 The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
 dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is    
 temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure 
 that it is spelled correctly. 

  Requested URL: /Inventory/ExportSheet
```

Comment: @tmack  Oh, do you mean "~/Inventory/ExportSheet"?

Comment: @tmack it is directly in the cshtml file.

Comment: @tmack would it be better if I used the 'Url.Action("ExportSheet")?model=' + JSON.stringify(model);  approach?

Comment: @tmack awesome!  Drop in an answer so I can give you credit!

Comment: Cleaning up my comments too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you deploying your application to the root of the Web Site in IIS? This line requires that you are:

```
window.location.href = "/Inventory/ExportSheet?....
```

I'd suggest using page-relative URLs instead so your app can be deployed somewhere under the root of the Site. That will be implemented in different ways depending on how you're serving your JS. If that is in a `script` tag on a server side page and you want to route to an MVC Action:

```
window.location.href = 'Url.Action("ExportSheet")?model=' + JSON.stringify(model);
```

should work.